# Checkerboard like rendering does not save performance

Tags: unity, shaders

I have a simple scene in Unity with a camera and a quad facing the camera filling the whole viewrect.
The quad has a material with the following shader:

```
Shader "Skip"
{
    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float4 screenPos : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.screenPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.vertex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                int2 screenUV = (i.screenPos.xy / i.screenPos.w) *_ScreenParams;
                bool skip = (screenUV.x + screenUV.y) % 2 == 0;
                if (skip) {
                    return fixed4(1,0,0,1);
                }else{
                    fixed4 clr = fixed4(0,0,1,1);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    {
                        clr += i % 2 -0.5;
                    }
                    return clr;
                }
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

The shader returns simple color for an even pixel and runs an expensive computation for an odd pixel.

There is no performance difference between running the expensive operation on all the pixels and running it on just half the pixels.

```
bool skip = (screenUV.x + screenUV.y) % 2 == 0; // ~13fps
bool skip = true; // ~2300fps
bool skip = false; // ~13fps
```

Why is there no improvement in performance?

Comment: I think this has todo with how GPUs work as they effectively run this on groups of cores (kernels) at the same time and the entire group can't be retasked to do other stuff until every single one has finished. So even if a single pixel needs the expensive calculation every pixel that is "cheap" has to wait for the expensive result. You could try playing with the kernal size of the shader to see if smaller groups make a difference?

Comment: What you've written here is not checkerboard rendering. In checkerboard rendering we first render to a lower-resolution buffer containing only the pixels we're drawing this frame (no skipping alternating pixels in the fragment shader), then in a second step we compose a resolved frame at twice the size where a checkerboard pattern of pixels are the latest samples straight from the newest low-res buffer, and the in-between pixels are reconstructed using interpolation/history/etc.